# Split rows into Columns

Tags: string, awk

In the following example I want to split the lines into two columns where column 1 is the string of letters and columns 2 is the number after the "-" sign.

```
      >1-1112309
      GTTTCCGTAGTGTAGTGGTTATCACGTTCGCCT
      >2-787704
      TGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTATAGTT
      >3-736193
      GTTTCCGTAGTGTAGTGGTTATCACGTTCGCC
      >4-671373
      TGTAAACATCCTCGACTGGAAGCT
```

Desired output:

```
           GTTTCCGTAGTGTAGTGGTTATCACGTTCGCCT        1112309
           TGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTATAGTT                   787704
           GTTTCCGTAGTGTAGTGGTTATCACGTTCGCC         736193
           TGTAAACATCCTCGACTGGAAGCT                 671373
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another `awk` command,

```
$ awk -v RS="\n>" '{gsub (/\n/," "); gsub (/^.*-/,"",$1); printf "%-40s %d\n", $2,$1}' file
GTTTCCGTAGTGTAGTGGTTATCACGTTCGCCT        1112309
TGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTATAGTT                   787704
GTTTCCGTAGTGTAGTGGTTATCACGTTCGCC         736193
TGTAAACATCCTCGACTGGAAGCT                 671373
```

RS is set to `\n>`. So it splits the input file into records according to the value(`\n>`) in RS variable.

```
gsub (/\n/," ") # Replaces all the newlines in each record with a space.

gsub (/^.*-/,"",$1) # Removes all the characters upto - in the column1.

printf "%-40s %d\n", $2,$1  # Prints column2, column1 in a formatted way.
```

Comment: Thanks. Still dont get how to tab separate the output. I though it was just \t

Comment: if you want the output to be tab seperated then try `awk -v RS="\n>" '{gsub (/\n/," "); gsub (/^.*-/,"",$1); print $2"\t"$1}' file.txt
`

Comment: you mean the tab at front?

Comment: if you want tab at the fron then try `awk -v RS="\n>" '{gsub (/\n/," "); gsub (/^.*-/,"",$1); printf "\t%-40s %d\n", $2,$1}' file.txt`

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F- '/^>/ {n = $2; next} {printf "%-40s %d\n", $0, n}' file
```

Explanation:

```
-F-      # set field separator to a dash

/^>/     # if line begins with a >
  {n = $2; next}  # then save second field and go on to next line in file

         # empty pattern matches every line (that makes it here)
  {printf "%-40s %d\n", $0, n}   # print current line in 40 columns left-justified
                                 # then print saved number and a newline
```

Comment: perfect. How do you preserve tabular output?

Comment: The `printf` format specifications line things up. You'll have to read up on that yourself! See http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf.html